# Selecting observations which have duplicate values in one column

Tags: r, duplicates

In R,I have data called main, with a column called Pass.id which is an identifier for a particular event. The values within this column are either unique, or there are pairs

```
Row  Pass.Id
1      300
2      300
3      301
4      302
5      302
6      303
```

So I would be looking to extract rows 1,2,4,5 into a new dataframe

I have spent much time on this but cant work it out. Any help appreciated.

Comment: following duplicate link: `df[(duplicated(df$Pass.Id) | duplicated(df$Pass.Id, fromLast = TRUE)), ]`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I prefer the single call to duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more complicated than it might appear on its face. My solution is a little messy, but should work, though you may have to adapt it since I don't have a dput of your data. I'll explain each piece, so hopefully that will help.

The first step is to find those index values with a duplicate.

```
duplicated(main$Pass.Id)
# This is a logical vector with TRUE for the second or later occurrence of some value
```

Because the above logical vector is `TRUE` only starting with the second occurence, you need to find the actual values:

```
main$Pass.Id[duplicated(main$Pass.Id)]
# This is a vector of the same class of x that only contains those values that occur more than once
```

Then you find those elements in the row that are in the above vector and extract them.

```
main$Pass.Id %in% main$Pass.Id[duplicated(main$Pass.Id)]
# This is a logical vector that is TRUE for each occurrence of any value that is in x more than one time.
# This logical vector is different from the first one, because it includes the first occurence of a duplicate value (not just the second and any later occurrences)
```

There are a number of ways to extract the columns for which a logical vector is TRUE.  In base R, you'd do:

```
main[main$Pass.Id %in% main$Pass.Id[duplicated(main$Pass.Id)], ]
# Don't forget the comma, which says you're extracting rows.
```

With dplyr, you could do:

```
filter(main, Pass.Id %in% Pass.Id[duplicated(Pass.Id)])
```